# Is there a way to have less if-statements?

Tags: java, if-statement

This program is supposed to print out the number of times each number has been generated of 100 random numbers in the scale of 1 to 10 (then put it in the array).

I can't think of any other way than to have an if-statement for each number. 
Is there any way to avoid so many if statements by another code or something?

```
public static void countNumbers() {
    Random generator = new Random();

    int arr[] = new int[101];
    int add[] = new int[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        int sum = 0;
        arr[i] = generator.nextInt(10)+1;

        if(arr[i] ==1){
            add[0]++;
        }
        if(arr[i] ==2){
            add[1]++;
        }
        if(arr[i] ==3){
            add[2]++;
        }
        if(arr[i] ==4){
            add[3]++;
        }
        if(arr[i] ==5){
            add[4]++;
        }
        if(arr[i] ==6){
            add[5]++;
        }
        if(arr[i] ==7){
            add[6]++;
        }
        if(arr[i] ==8){
            add[7]++;
        }
        if(arr[i] ==9){
            add[8]++;
        }
        if(arr[i] ==10){
            add[9]++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(add));
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: This has a pattern. You can use that. In general you could use `switch` statements which don't have a pattern.

Comment: Replace all your if statements with `add[i <= 0 ? 0 : i - 1]++;`

Answer (score 7):

You should note that all your if statements have a similar structure :

```
if(arr[i] ==x){
    add[x-1]++;
}
```

Therefore they can be replaced by `add[arr[i]-1]++;`.

You only need a single if statement to validate that you don't get out of the bounds of the `add` array :

```
if (arr[i] <= 10 && arr[i] >= 1) {
     add[arr[i]-1]++;
}
```

EDIT :

As assylias commented, you don't really need the if statement, since you initialize your `arr` array to values between 1 and 10.

Comment: your condition is redundant - `arr[i]` will always be between 1 and 10.

Comment: to add to Eran's answer: even if you need several if's: if they cancel each other out, use if - else if, to avoid a lot of unnecessary conditions being checked

Answer (score 3):

**Yes.**

If you notice, you have a repeating pattern:

```
if(arr[i] == 1){
    add[0]++;
}
```

Then you can replace it with the next one:

```
add[arr[i] - 1]++;
```

And the resulting `for` will look alike:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    arr[i] = generator.nextInt(10) + 1;
    add[arr[i] - 1]++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your whole method can be replaced by:

```
public static void countNumbers() {
    Random generator = new Random();

    int add[] = new int[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        add[generator.nextInt(10)]++;
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(add));
    System.out.println();
}
```

The other variables (such as the `arr` array) are not used at the moment so I suggest getting rid of them until you actually need them.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is good to re-use the size of you `add[]` this way you can keep your code more flexible.

```
int add[] = new int[10];

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    int index = generator.nextInt(add.length);
    arr[index]++;
}
```